# Ancova simulation:Power Analysis

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I am a college student taking a stats class on ecological design and need help figuring out how to go through a power analysis in R. I am using an ANCOVA design with no interaction; in this hypothetical experiment there are two flower varieties planted in independent plots and for each plot the explanatory variable collected is soil moisture with the response being flower yield.

I simulated a dataset called sim.flowers that has in it an alpha effect for the difference between flowers, a slope, an n for my x values, and a sigma for a normal distribution I will use in my y vector (following an ancova model of y = alpha + beta0 + beta1X; for simplicity I made the intercept 0) See below:

```
sim.flowers <- function(alpha,slope,n,sigma) {
x <-runif(2*n, min = -1, max = 1) 
flower.effects <- rep(c(0,alpha),each=n) #there are two different flower varieties and I gave them a true difference of 1. 
y <- flower.effects + slope * x  + rnorm(2*n, 0, sigma)
data.frame(x=x,y=y,flower.effects = flower.effects)
}
```

I tested that out and it worked, it gave me a data set with an X a Y and column for flower effects

```
> test1 <- sim.oats(1,0.5,3,0.3)
> test1
        x           y        flower.effects
1 -0.99913780 -0.31373866           0
2 -0.38610391  0.41070965           0
3 -0.58308522  0.07426254           0
4 -0.35900237  0.36395132           1
5 -0.07296464  1.29149447           1
6  0.18575996  0.85001847           1
```

The goal is to create a figure showing power to detect the flower Variety effect, with different lines for different numbers of replicates for each flower Variety treatment for this I was told to should choose only 1 value of the Soil Moisture effect.

And a figure showing power to detect the Soil Moisture effect, with different lines for different numbers of replicates for each flower Variety treatment, choosing 1 value of the flower Variety

To  start to get here I ran a linear regression in a for loop so that I could extract p-values and be able to plot a power graph setting the probability to reject the null at 0.5 my code is below

```
> sim.flowers.many <- function(alpha,slope,n,sigma,numsimulations){
+   pvals <-numeric(numsimulations)
+   for(i in 1:numsimulations){
+       thisdat <-sim.flowers(alpha,slope,n,sigma)
+       thisfit <-lm(y~x,thisdat)
+     pvals[i]<-coefficients(summary(thisfit))['x','Pr(>|t|)']
+   }
+   return(pvals)
+ }
> sim.flowers.many( alpha = 1,slope = 0.5, n = 3, sigma = 6, numsimulations =3)
[1] 0.7662218 0.4454654 0.2414637
```

I seem to be getting p-values alright. I did the following with the expectation that I would get a dataframe with a column that states the probability of rejecting the null so that I could just plot it out.

```
> determine.power <- function(true.slopes){
+     true.slopes <-0:3
+     out<- data.frame(true.slopes,prob.reject.null=NA)
+       for(i in 1:length(true.slopes)){
+       thesepvals <- sim.flowers.many(alpha = 1,slope = 0.5, n = 3, sigma = 6, numsimulations =3)
+       out[i,2] <- mean(thesepvals < 0.05)
+         }
+     return(out)
+     }
```

I got this as an output:

```
> determine.power(true.slopes=0.5)
    true.slopes prob.reject.null
1           0        0.0000000
2           1        0.0000000
3           2        0.3333333
4           3        0.3333333
```

And thought I could graph it out like this:

```
 power.results <- determine.power(seq(0, 2, by = 0.2))
 plot(prob.reject.null ~ true.slopes, data = power.results, main = "Power analysis", xlab     = "true slope", 
ylab = "Prob. reject null", ylim = c(0,1), type = "b", col = "slateblue4") 
 grid(col = "hotpink")
```

While I seem to be understanding the writing of the code needed for a power analysis I'm having trouble understanding how to create the two figures that I'm supposed to. I don't know how to change this code so that the power figures I generate reflect the effects of soil moisture and flower variety. I would appreciate any help with working through this problem and I apologize for the length but I felt it was necessary context for the question I am asking.

Comment: Look at page 10 of [this document](http://www.evolutionarystatistics.org/document.pdf). Do you think you followed all the steps?

Answer (score -1):

You can compare your results with `pwr.f2.test{pwr}`